# Renaming files sometimes doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

Similar questions have been asked but this is really a question in its own right since I can't figure out why it's happening.

This is the code I'm currently using to rename a file:

```
$name = $titles . $vidid . '.' . 'ogg';
$newname = preg_replace("/[^\w-(). !]/", "", $name);
$fixedname = str_replace($vidid, '', $newname);
rename($newname, $fixedname);
```

$name would look something like 'Lyrics: John Newman - Love Me Again-vDx27Ye2gC4.ogg', so I'm trying to remove all unsupported characters and the video URL which is added to them.

The code above works most of the time, but occasionally it won't, and I'll be left with 2 files:

```
Lyrics: John Newman - Love Me Again-vDx27Ye2gC4.ogg (0 bytes + original name)

Lyrics - John Newman - Love Me Again-vDx27Ye2gC4.ogg (normal size + removed special characters)
```

So it seems it's being renamed incorrectly (without removing the URL) and keeps a 0 byte copy of the old file.

I know the $vidid is equal to the URL, so it's completely random.

What I'm trying to achieve is to rename something like this:

```
Lyrics: John Newman - Love Me Again-vDx27Ye2gC4.ogg
```

To this:

```
Lyrics John Newman - Love Me Again.ogg
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what error message `rename` returns?

Comment: I get this error:
`PHP Warning:  rename(Lyrics: John Newman - Love Me Again-vDx27Ye2gC4.ogg,Lyrics John Newman - Love Me Again.ogg):  No such file or directory in /xxx/xxx` so I changed the rename from `rename($newname, $fixedname)` to `rename($name, $fixedname)` and it changes the filename successfully, BUT I'm left with a 0 byte file, where the original filename that's left as well has all the data. What I don't get is, why does `rename($newname, $fixedname)` work occasionally, and other times not.